# Database connection when using offline editing GIT project

Tags: php, database, git, testing

When working on a project offline, checked out from a GIT repository, how do I manage the database connection.

I know I could set up a local copy of the database which seems sensible but what is the correct way to manage switching between the different connection details with in the code or is there another option I'm not considering?

Comment: Just have a configuration file that has the connection details of the database rather than hard coding it?

Comment: so we have a config file which is included into all files which contains the connection to the db, are you saying we should alter the config file each time to hook up to a local testing database or is there a more efficient way to do this?